# using nsmutabledata to initialize string

Tags: objective-c

Im trying to get my data retrieved from a socket into a nsmutablearray.  however the examples and tutorials i found showed it going into a string first.  which is fine i can parse it out from there.  but i cant even get this string thing working.

```
    case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
    {

        if(!rawData) {
            rawData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
        }
        uint8_t buf[1024];
        unsigned int len = 0;
        len = [(NSInputStream *)theStream read:buf maxLength:1024];
        if(len) {
         [rawData initWithBytes:buf length:len];
            int bytesRead;
            bytesRead += len;

            [self messageReceived:rawData];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"no buffer!");
        }
        NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:rawData 
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"data buffer: %@ |~|string buffer%@",rawData,str);


        [str release];
        break;
    }
```

But as you will see from the output below the string never gets any of the data (well actually i think its an encoding problem, and so i think it just looks empty)

> 2011-09-27 13:14:06.356 Cameleon[30095:207] data buffer: <0f000102>
>   |~|string buffer
>
> 2011-09-27 13:14:06.359 Cameleon[30095:207] data buffer: <02000400
>   000003> |~|string buffer
>
> 2011-09-27 13:14:06.458 Cameleon[30095:207] data buffer: <05000500
>   00020300> |~|string buffer
>
> 2011-09-27 13:14:06.659 Cameleon[30095:207] data buffer: <05000b00
>   0008080e 13163809 2711> |~|string buffer
>
> 2011-09-27 13:14:06.663 Cameleon[30095:207] data buffer: <05000700
>   00040101 005a> |~|string buffer

i want the string buffer to mirror the values of the databuffer
or an array with each byte of the data buffer

ANSWER:

```
case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
        {

            if(!rawData) {
                rawData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
            }
            uint8_t buf[1024];
            unsigned int len = 0;
            len = [(NSInputStream *)theStream read:buf maxLength:1024];
            if(len) {
             [rawData initWithBytes:buf length:len];                
            } else {
                NSLog(@"no buffer!");
            }

            const uint8_t *bytes = [rawData bytes];

            NSMutableArray *mutableBuffer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:len];  

            for (int i =0; i < [rawData length]; i++) {
                [mutableBuffer addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X", bytes[i]]];
            }
            [self gateKeeper:mutableBuffer];


            [mutableBuffer release];
            break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several problems.  First off, this is not the usual pattern for allocating an `NSData` object:

```
rawData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
```

Although technically correct in terms of memory management, it's non-idiomatic and results in an unnecessary pair of `autorelease` and `retain` messages getting sent.  It should instead be this:

```
rawData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
```

Secondly, this code is useless:

```
int bytesRead;
bytesRead += len;
```

You're declaring a variable, failing to initialize it, adding `len` to it (which is technically Undefined Behavior, but on x86 this will be harmless), and then doing nothing with it.  You probably want to use a longer-lived variable declared outside of this block and initialize it properly.

Finally, the actual cause of your problem is that the data you're receiving is not UTF-8 text.  It's some kind of binary data with embedded NUL characters (the zero bytes).  When these get converted to strings, the NULs signal termination of the string, so nothing after them gets printed.

Just keep the data you have as an `NSData`, don't bother trying to convert it to a string if it's not actually textual data.  What sort of data are you dealing with?  Where is it coming from?

Comment: the bytesread stuff and that retain option where from the tutorials i was reading (the retain i could have sworn i got from the apple dev site)  in any case i need that NSDATA to be put into an NSARRAY or NSMUTABLEARRAY so i can work with it (parse it).

Comment: i need to be able to operate on/parse the individual bytes

Comment: here is the link that uses retain.  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/ReadingInputStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002273-BCIJHAGD     im not doing this to say im right, but to kinda say why; do they use retain?   (but not as important as main question)

Comment: @owen: I don't know why that tutorial says `[[NSMutableData data] retain]`.  It's not *wrong* (as in it won't result in memory leaks or crashes), but it's not the usual way of doing it.  Give the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) a thorough read-through.  As for operating on the individual bytes, you already have them with the `NSData` object: just call `[rawData bytes]` to get the pointer, and do what you want with that.

Comment: i have tried using [rawdata bytes] but i dont understand how to get my bytes from that.  thats why i went to this nsstring options (i could easily use substring).  i will play with this some more however and see if i can get it working.

Comment: @owen: You just write `const uint8_t *bytes = [rawData bytes`] if you're using Objective-C or `const uint8_t *bytes = (const uint8_t *)[rawData bytes]` if you're using Objective-C++, it returns a pointer to the raw byte array.  You access the individual bytes using the normal C array syntax: `bytes[0]` is the first byte, `bytes[1]` is the second byte, etc.